# How To Send Emoji With Text In Blazor SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I have developed a private chat application using blazor server signalR where we can addfriend and chat with them privately.
Now, what I want is to send the emoji and text message.
What I have done to get emoji in input text box is that I have given Id `id="mytext"` to input which is bind to `@bind="MsgBody"` and that is passed to javascript function `SetElemetById(id)`.
Now, the problem is that the `MsgBody` is null on button click `@onclick="SendMessage"` when Javascript function `SetElemetById(id)` is called in input, if its not called then we have value in `MsgBody` but we don't have emoji in input.
Any help with my code or any idea how can i send emoji and text will be great. Thank you

Below is my razor component html

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="mytext" @bind="MsgBody" class="form-control Message-Input">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SendMessage"> Send</button><br><br>
```

Below is my code to call javascript function

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await iJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("SetElemetById","mytext");
}
```

Below is my javascript function

```
function SetElemetById(id) {
    var getTextBoxId = document.getElementById(id)
    $(getTextBoxId).emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom"
    });
};
```

Below is my code to save message from input

```
    public async Task SendMessage()
    {
      dualMessage.MessageBody = MsgBody; // MsgBody is null
      dualMessage.SendOn = DateTime.Now;
      mainService.SaveChatMessage(dualMessage);
    }
```

Comment: @enet thank you for the help with my previous question, can you help me with this current question please

Comment: Is MsgBody also null in case you not all the java script?

Comment: @Danel W MsgBody is null when javascript is called, if JavaScript is not called there is value in MsgBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is wrong. Blazor Data-binding engine ignores any changes you render to the Html tags. Thus you can't affect the data binding of the input text element from JavaScript. This is why the MsgBody variable is always null. But even if you could, you should first try to implement every thing in Blazor, and if it proves impossible, resort to JSInterop.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await iJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("SetElemetById","mytext");
}
```

Just for the records, you should initialize your JS objects from the OnAfterRender(Async) pairs, and only once; that is you call your init functions from within the if statement like this:

```
if(firstRender)
{
  // Call your JS init functions
}
```

Try the following to implement the emoji functionality:

1. Go to [Github](https://github.com/wsdt/RealtimeChat_WebAssembly) and download the repository Code
2. Unzip it... It is unzipped into a folder named:
   `RealtimeChat_WebAssembly-master`
3. This folder contains two folders: `EmojiPicker` and `WSDTChat.` The `EmojiPicker` folder is empty. Why ? I did not waste time to learn.
4. However, I solved this issue by downloading the code from [here](https://github.com/wsdt/Blazor_EmojiFilePicker/tree/0b39df4a3f8f16152d45fa44e14782f86ed2bc4e)
5. Extracted the folder, and then copied its content into the `EmojiPicker`
   folder. Do that...
6. Open the solution in Visual Studio, build the solution, and then execute the
   command: `update-database` in the Package Manager Console in order to create the
   database. Now run the app and test it.
7. Do test the functionality of adding emojis, as well as photos.
8. Now, what you have to do is follow the relevant code to understand how the guy
   implemented the use of emojis...copy the necessary code and apply it to your
   chat.
9. You may adopt from this app functionalities your app is missing as well as the
   UI look and behavior.

Please do the above, and if you have encountered any issue let me know. If you are a programmer, then you should happily try to solve all the issues alone. But I'm here, and I'm not a programmer;}

Comment: Thank you enet but is there any way I can make my code have the emoji functionality using my way

Comment: Do you mean using a JavaScript plug-in, such as the one offered by Jquery ? Yes, you can, and you'll have to use JSInterop, no data-binding, etc. I heartily suggest you don't go that path. But if you do, show complete code of what you did, and I'll help you resolve the issues encountered. But again, don't do that. Incidentally, your code posted in your question contains basic attempt to gain this functionality, and of course, you can't use data-binding. But it's all up to you to decide. Start to work on it, and come up with questions.

Comment: thank you this git suggestion worked for me thank you

Comment: @sudip chand, Very glad that you did it that way. That was the right path to take. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Why not making it without javascript?

Define a array with the utf32 emojis you want and create a keypad in the browser to add those emojis.

```
<!-- Emoji Keyboard -->
<div>
  @foreach (var c in emojis)
  {
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" @onclick="(() => AddEmoji(c))" >@c</button>
  }
</div>

@code {
   //List of emojis
   String[] emojis = new String[] { "\U0001F600", "\U0001F601", "\U0001F602", "\U0001F602" };

   //Add Emoji to Message
   protected async Task AddEmoji(string emoji)
   {
       MsgBody += emoji;
       StateHasChanged();
   }
```

Comment: No StateHasChanged(), please.